# How would you find the highest three numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was given a question:

> Given an arrayOfInts, find the highestProduct you can get from three
>   of the integers.
>
> Input:  var a = [1,7,9,2]; Expected Output:  7*9*2 = 126

How would we solve this problem? I've written the code but in vain.

```
function highestProductIntegers(a){
  var h1, h2,h3; //three highest number pointers.

  a.forEach(function(val, index){
    if(index=0){
      h1 = val; //assign the first element to h1 (Highest 1)
    }

    h2 = val; //second to h2

    if( val > h1 ){ //if second is greater than h1 make it h1 || h2 || h3
      h3 = h2;
      h2 = h1;
      h1 = val;
    }
    else if(val<h1 && val > h2) //keep comparing for all elements.
      h2 = val;
    else if(val < h1 && val < h2)
      h3 = val;
    else if(val < h1 && val < h2 && val > h3)
      h3=val;
  });

    return h1*h2*h3; 
}
```

Is there any easier or efficient way of solving this problem?

Comment: Sort then multiply the first 3 numbers. The properties of multiplication are such that you do not need to compare products. The biggest numbers make the biggest products.

Comment: This question is harder than it appears: Note that none of the answers below work for test case `[-50, -10, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @JeffBowman Yes it is, I have commented on the signed answer about a fact may be related to your opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three short steps.

- sort them in a descending order.
- slice it to get the three (highest) integers
- use `reduce` function to multiply it and get the result.

```js
var a = [17, 1, 7, 9, 2, 5, 9, 15, 12, 44],
    r = a.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 3).reduce((a, b) => a * b);
    console.log(r);
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in the code. Why did you sort, slice and reduce? I'm trying to learn slice and reduce, would help! @Kind user

Comment: @TechnoCorner It's fixed.

Comment: I know it's an amateur question. Why do we need to do function(a,b){return b-a} ? Why can't we use regualr array.sort()?

Comment: @TechnoCorner Because `sort` function watches only the first digit in a number. For example, if you use `sort()` on following array: `[1,2,3,11]` it will return `[1,11,2,3]`.

Comment: i did upvote, i am just trying out other cases. I will mark your answer :-) (Infact I upvoted both your answers)

Comment: @TechnoCorner Thank you. Cheers!

Comment: When learning programming basics this is not the suitable solution, although it is **the best practically**, I can bit, it is an exercise meant by looping and control structure.

Comment: _"Because sort function watches only the first digit in a number"_ That's wrong... @TechnoCorner: [`Array.prototype.sort(compareFunction)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): _"If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order.  For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order."_

Comment: @Andreas I should have mentioned about converting numbers to string, but then it's likely the same. The first letter is being compared, still.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highestProductIntegers(array){
array.sort(function(i,k){return k-i;});
return array[0]*array[1]*array[2];
}
```

Comment: it should be  return k-i instead of k-1